# Create a water + baking soda solution?

Tags: water, baking-soda

I was wondering if there is a way I can mix the two and put it in a spray bottle? I would like to use water + baking soda in some cases to spray a little rather than have large amounts. Is it possible? I've tried, but the nozzle always ends up clogged.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Is this a cooking question? (And have you tried, well, mixing them and putting them in a spray bottle?)

Comment: Im trying to create a solution that is ready to be used whenever I need to for any relevant cooking session. However putting baking soda and water in a bottle will always end up unsaturated around the nozzle and causes it to be clogged. Im wondering if anyone ever tried to do this and was successful ?

Comment: But what do you cook that uses baking soda water solution, in tiny spray quantities? There might be a better way, assuming you are cooking something (and not, say, cleaning).

Comment: Some cultures use small amounts of baking soda (sodium carbonate) solution on demand as a common baking additive, or assistant. e.g. glaze for baked goods, dough strengthener (pulled noodles)

Comment: I'm guessing they are wanting to tenderise meat, was thinking along similar lines for ease and constant distribution of bicarb and presumably easier to rinse off. But having read other posts I don't think it seems that good of idea.

Comment: Just wanted to add, for the naysayers, that spraying baking soda on food seems like a very reasonable thing to want to do. Baking soda lowers the pH, which strongly encourages the Maillard reaction (in the presence of protein and a "reducing sugar"), resulting in much faster and deeper browning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small pot of water and baking soda (over saturated is OK), and a simple brush is all you need

A quick stir of the pot with the brush, and wash it on what you need works fine

Answer (score 7):

[Baking soda is soluble in water at up to 90 grams per liter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate). If you add more than that to water, you'll end up with a saturated solution at 90 g/L plus some crystalline baking soda on the bottom of the container.

A teaspoon of baking soda has a mass of about 4.8 grams, so it'll take 53 ml of your saturated soda solution to deliver 1 teaspoon baking soda. In Fully metric terms, that's 11.1 ml of solution per gram baking soda.

Comment: The OP is probably already doing essentially this. The issue is presumably that the solution in the nozzle evaporates and leaves behind baking soda.

Comment: OP should use a squeeze bottle rather than a spray bottle. Something like this won't clog nearly as easily: http://skincandytattoosupply.com/products.php?product=Squeeze-Bottle

Comment: THe OP should explain what he's trying to accomplish; without any extra information I assume that for some reason he needs a fine mist of baking soda solution.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger , thanks thats a good alternative as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I really have no idea why you'd need to do this for cooking. The amount of baking soda in solution in a few sprays of a bottle is going to be tiny. If this is actually cooking related, I'm sure there's a better way.

But if there's some use for your spray bottle of solution, you probably just need to clean the nozzle periodically - spraying plain water through it now and then would work. Nothing's going to stop the water in the nozzle from evaporating, though.

Comment: Just looked back at your comments on this question, hilarious.